# Forecasting - 3 independent variables

Tags: python, forecasting

I have 3 independent input variables: time, temperature and pressure, and one output - usefulness.

Example:

Number of the sample; Time; Temperature; Pressure; Usefulness 
1;1;30;50;9% 
2;3;50;50;80% 
3;5;50;40;75% 
4;7;50;40;?%

I want to train my network and predict the usefulness for the last sample. Which model of forecasting should I use? ARIMA? For coding, I use python.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The name of the model is ARMAX, which is a model dependent of exogenous and endogenous (lagged) variable.

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/351146/fit-an-armax-model-in-r